# maven determine default lifecycle phase for plugin

Tags: maven, plugins, lifecycle

I'm using a maven plugin and I'm trying to determine that default goal it binds to. Is there a command to run to figure that out?

I was able go into the source and find the `@phase` annotation, but I would like to be able to figure it out from the command line if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the maven-help-plugin to get such kind of information:

For example for the maven-compiler-plugin:

```
mvn help:describe -DartifactId=maven-jar-plugin -DgroupId=org.apache.maven.plugins -Ddetail=true -Dgoal=jar
```